# How to get incoming IP address in Spray framework

Tags: http, scala, ip-address, akka, spray

I am looking at headers that are coming in, but no IP seems to be there:

```
HttpRequest(GET,http://127.0.0.1:8080/track/check,List(Accept-Language: uk-UA, 
uk, ru, en-US, en, Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 
(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29
Safari/537.36, Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, 
*/*;q=0.8, Connection: keep-alive, Host: 127.0.0.1:8080),EmptyEntity,HTTP/1.1)
```

This is a request I did from browser. Basically I am looking in:

```
path("check") {
       get {
         implicit request => {
           val a = 5
         }
       }
     } ~
```

Here request object doesn't have any information about the IP address. Any help is very appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using spray routing, then there is a directive for extracting client ip called `clientIP` =)
To use it just write:

```
(path("somepath") & get) {
  clientIP { ip =>
    complete(s"ip is $ip")
  }
}
```

more then simple, but you need still need to add explicit configuration to get IP from request. And a little comment, maybe i didn't get something but in spray there is no `implicit request`. Actually incoming request percolates through your routing structure, if you take a look into the routing library you'll see that route is just an alias: `type Route = RequestContext => Unit`. So if you need to get access to the context at some point just write:

```
(path("somepath") & get) {
  clientIP { ip => 
    reqCont => reqCont.complete(s"ip is $ip")
  }
}
```

But remember about static route part and dynamic part.

Comment: That's a good way, however my answer below is also very relevant. That was actually the main problem for me.

Answer (score 30):

The problem was in configuration, this is not documented well. Adding this:

```
# spray-can config
spray.can {
  server {
    remote-address-header = on
  }
}
```

forces spray to add remote IP header to the main headers. Address header will have name Remote-Address.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's currently underdocumented. Once we get to documenting the clientIp directive it will contain exactly that documentation. Sorry, that you had to find out the hard way.

Comment: @jrudolph Still missing. http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.3/spray-routing/misc-directives/clientIP/#description 2 years, no pressure.

Comment: @jrudolph What's on with the documentation? I have spent lot of time to get to this answer, which is most voted, but not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need both what Alex K and 4lex1v have posted.

The below config forces spray to add remote IP header to the main headers. Address header will have name Remote-Address.

```
# spray-can config
spray.can {
  server {
    remote-address-header = on
  }
}
```

You will then need to add the `clientIP` directive around the route.

```
(path("somepath") & get) {
  clientIP { ip =>
    complete(s"ip is $ip")
  }
}
```

This will return an object of type `RemoteAddress`, from which you can extract the IP.

```
remoteAddress.toOption.map(_.getHostAddress).getOrElse("Unknown")
```

The `clientIP` directive will extract the IP if it exists, however the header that it extracts the value from will not be recorded unless you set the `remote-address-header` flag to `on`. It defaults to `off`.

More info can now be found in the Spray documentation. http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.4/spray-routing/misc-directives/clientIP/#example